# Mapbox navigation launcher add waypoints names

Tags: android, mapbox

We are creating a navigation by using mapbox navigation launcher, it is working fine untill we have added the waypoints names. After adding waypoints name application started to crash randomly (some time at 1st waypoint, some time at another). Every time erorr is same "Number of waypoint names must match  the number of waypoints provided "

Here is our code :

```
     List<TourDetailResponse.TourDetailsPoi> pois = tourDetailResponse.getPois();

    Point origin = Point.fromLngLat(currentLongitude, currentLatitude);

    Point destination = Point.fromLngLat(pois.get(pois.size()-1).getLongitude(), pois.get(pois.size()-1).getLatitude());

    NavigationRoute.Builder  builder = NavigationRoute.builder(coreActivity)
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
            .origin(origin)
            .destination(destination)


    .profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_WALKING);


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    sb.append("origin##");

        for(int q=0;q<pois.size()-1;q++)
    {
        Point point = Point.fromLngLat(pois.get(q).getLongitude(), pois.get(q).getLatitude());

        builder.addWaypoint(point);
        sb.append(pois.get(q).getName()+"##");
    }

    builder.language(Locale.getDefault());

    sb.append(pois.get(pois.size()-1).getName()+"##");

    sb.setLength(sb.length()-2);

    try
    {
       builder.addWaypointNames(sb.toString().split("##"));
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In Debug mode we have checked that Number of waypoint names are same as the number of waypoints

> Stack trace : Fatal Exception:
>   com.mapbox.core.exceptions.ServicesException: Number of waypoint names
>   must match  the number of waypoints provided.
>          at com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.MapboxDirections$Builder.build(MapboxDirections.java:757)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute$Builder.build(NavigationRoute.java:558)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.route.RouteFetcher.executeRouteCall(RouteFetcher.java:120)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.route.RouteFetcher.findRouteFromRouteProgress(RouteFetcher.java:72)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.ViewRouteFetcher.fetchRouteFromOffRouteEvent(ViewRouteFetcher.java:65)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationViewModel.sendEventOffRoute(NavigationViewModel.java:410)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationViewModel.access$600(NavigationViewModel.java:47)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationViewModel$2.userOffRoute(NavigationViewModel.java:274)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationEventDispatcher.onUserOffRoute(NavigationEventDispatcher.java:150)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.RouteProcessorThreadListener.onUserOffRoute(RouteProcessorThreadListener.java:57)
>          at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.RouteProcessorHandlerCallback$1.run(RouteProcessorHandlerCallback.java:99)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got reply from the mapbox, It is bug on their side.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/1160